# Not able to consume kafka events remotely Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 5.6.7.8:9092

Tags: python, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have set up my kafka producer a fresh following the tutorial mentioned here: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-14-04

I am pushing some events to the producer using cron and following script on server with IP: 1.2.3.4

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading, logging, time
import multiprocessing
import requests
import datetime
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer

class CheckApis():
    apisList = {"a": "https://test.eng.com/"}
    kafkaProducer = "1.2.3.4:9092"
    kafkaTopic = "sometopic"
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafkaProducer)
    for key, value in apisList.items():
        headers = {};
        response = requests.request("GET", value, headers=headers)
        message = {"app_name": key, "status": response.status_code, "message": "none", "timestamp": str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())}
        producer.send(kafkaTopic, json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'));
        print (response.text)
        print (response.status_code)
    producer.close()
```

This works well, and I can see the pushed events using this command:

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 1.2.3.4:2181 --topic sometopic --from-beginning
```

But when I try to use these events remotely from other server (my laptop), it fails with error:

> error: Some error occured while listening to kafka events Error:
>   connect ECONNREFUSED 5.6.7.8:9092 (Some different IP here not 1.2.3.4)

Here is my consumer code (in node js using kafka-node):

```
var ConsumerGroup = require('kafka-node').ConsumerGroup;
    var healthConsumerOption = {
        host: '1.2.3.4:2181',
        autoCommit: true,
        groupId: os.hostname(),
        sessionTimeout: 15000,
        protocol: ['roundrobin'],
        fromOffset: 'latest'
    };
    var healthConsumerGroup = new ConsumerGroup(healthConsumerOption, healthTopics);
        listenHealthEventsKafka: function(connections){
            try{
                healthConsumerGroup.on('error', onError);
                healthConsumerGroup.on('message', onMessage);
                healthConsumerGroup.on('connect', function(){
                    logger.info("Health consumer group is ready. ")
                });

                function onMessage(message){
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(message.value);
                    console.log(message);
                };

                function onError(error){
                    logger.error("Some error occured while listening to kafka events " +error);
                }

                process.once('SIGNINT', function(){
                    async.each([healthConsumerGroup], function(consumer, callback){
                        logger.info("Closing the kafka health consumer process ");
                        consumer.close(true, callback);
                    });
                })
            }catch(error){
                logger.error("Could not connect to kafka events for build " +error);
            }
        }
```

Do I need to do additional configuration on Kafka server (server.properties) to allow remote access.. or I am doing anything wrong? Please help.

Comment: So what is this second IP that it complains about not being able to connect to? It must have been set somewhere...

Comment: What is the advertised hostname for the brokers? Clients need to be able to route to that.

Comment: I dont know from where this 2nd IP is coming, I have never mentioned it anywhere in my code.. (its not even IP of my laptop) @Thilo

Comment: My guess is that is the IP of the Kafka broker. Which is configured at the broker-side. The client gets this from Zookeeper or a bootstrap broker. If this is an internal network IP, you cannot just access it from your network without some deep routing or VPN magic.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499527/access-kafka-broker-in-a-remote-machine-error?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

On your Kafka broker `server.properties` you need to set `advertised.listeners` to the *external IP* so that clients can correctly connect to it. Otherwise they'll try to connect to the internal IP (since `advertised.listeners` will default to `listeners` unless explicitly set)

Ref: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

See also https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem for a Dockerized instance.